# PHP simply wanna echo this week sunday and this week saturday, same for last week

Tags: php

i read a lot of long articles and answers but none of this describes this simply, all talk about different variables and many of them give differnt week starting date...

just wanna say

this week

```
$thissunday= xxxx; (in dd/mm/yyyy)
$thissaturday=yyyy; (in dd/mm/yyyy)
```

and the previous week

```
$lastsunday= xxxx; (in dd/mm/yyyy)
$lastsaturday=xxx; (in dd/mm/yyyy)
```

I tried this

```
$thisws = strtotime('Sunday this week');
$thiswe = strtotime('Saturday this week');
$lastws = strtotime('Sunday last week');
$lastwe = strtotime('Saturday last week');
```

and gives long useless number seems timestamp

is it that complicated!?

Comment: Don't disrespect the unix timestamp.

Comment: I don't disrespect the unix or the timestamp nor both of them together, I understand what they are and solved many things to me already... I just meant that they are useless this way, I wanted a way to rap them up so I can use them. thanks Charlie.

Comment: Oh I'm just playing, buddy. Once you realize the power of http://php.net/date in formatting timestamps, you'll wish everything was *already* available to you as timestamps!

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

That "useless number" is a UNIX timestamp.

[UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

As the [strototime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) documentation says: "Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp"

Comment: does NOT give correct dates. see this: $thisws=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Sunday this week')); $thiswe=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Saturday this week')); $lastws=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Sunday last week')); $lastwe=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Saturday last week')); returns this week: 22/02/2015 - 21/02/2015 and last week 15/02/2015to14/02/2015 that is not correct

Comment: Feb 22 is indeed this coming Sunday. Feb 21 is indeed this coming Saturday. Feb 15 was indeed last Sunday. What's the issue?

Comment: Thanks again Charlie, I understood the concept now, thought like last sunday is the sunday of the last week grrrrrrrr this makes more logic, also got some other documentation about how to use last sunday -1 week and it is great :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function after [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) like so:

```
<?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Sunday last week'));
```

Comment: well, that works but does NOT give correct dates. see this:

$thisws=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Sunday this week'));
$thiswe=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Saturday this week'));
$lastws=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Sunday last week'));
$lastwe=date('d/m/Y', strtotime('Saturday last week'));

returns
this week: 22/02/2015 - 21/02/2015
and last week 15/02/2015to14/02/2015

that is not correct